# WriteError(u'could not find host matching read preference { mode: "primary", tags: [ {} ] } for set shard2ReplSet',)

Tags: mongodb, collections, sharding

When i update a sharding collection, following problem happened. Please help.

> 2017-08-03T17:35:14.231+0800 I COMMAND  [ftdc] serverStatus was very
> slow: { after basic: 0, after asserts: 0, after backgroundFlushing: 0,
> after connections: 0, after dur: 0, after extra_info: 12238, after
> globalLock: 12238, after locks: 12238, after network: 12238, after
> opLatencies: 12238, after opcounters: 12238, after opcountersRepl:
> 12238, after repl: 12238, after security: 12238, after storageEngine:
> 12238, after tcmalloc: 12238, after wiredTiger: 12238, at end: 12238 }
> 2017-08-03T17:35:14.384+0800 I -        [conn19] end connection
> 172.16.11.119:39352
>
> (25 connections now open) 2017-08-03T17:35:14.384+0800 I -
> [conn22] end connection 172.16.11.139:59942
>
> (25 connections now open) 2017-08-03T17:35:15.130+0800 I -
> [conn16] end connection 172.16.11.118:45782
>
> (23 connections now open) 2017-08-03T17:35:23.582+0800 I ASIO
> [NetworkInterfaceASIO-ShardRegistry-0] Ending idle connection to host
> 172.16.11.139:21000
>
> because the pool meets constraints; 1 connections to that host remain open

Comment: What do you mean by *"when i update a sharding collection"*? Are you talking about "updating documents" or are you "changing sharding configuration". If the latter then you should be asking on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com), which is the place to ask your database configuration questions. The general error suggests that you are in fact "changing the sharding configurarion" and that it has not come as the result of anything else.

Comment: updating documents

Comment: You need to show what you are actually doing to "reproduce the error". Again though the error shown is actually more indicative of "incorrect sharding configuration". So whilst a reproducible error in "updating documents" would be "on-topic" for StackOverflow, if the "reproduction" involved your specific steps for "sharding configuration", then it would be **"off-topic"** and due to the configuration and therefore to be asked on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: If you think you are **on-topic** then show the steps to reproduce, which is also a requirement here. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)